# Удалить свойства из json-объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-events, json.net

JSON-объекты формируются из excel-файла функцией:

```
var ExcelToJSON = function (sheetNameRead) {

        // Get The File From The Input
        var oFile = document.getElementById('uploadFile').files[0];
        //var oFile = oFileIn.target.files[0];
        var sFilename = oFile.name;
        // Create A File Reader HTML5
        var reader = new FileReader();

        var json_objects = [];
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            // Ready The Event For When A File Gets Selected
            reader.onload = function (event) {
                var data = event.target.result;
                var cfb = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
                // Loop Over Each Sheet
                cfb.SheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName) {

                    if (sheetName == sheetNameRead) {
                        // Obtain The Current Row As CSV
                        var sCSV = XLS.utils.make_csv(cfb.Sheets[sheetName]);
                        var json_object = XLS.utils.sheet_to_json(cfb.Sheets[sheetName]);

                        //json_objects.push(json_object.select("oIDobject personalAccount idAccrual dateAccrual summAccrual datePayment summPayment"));

                        json_objects.push(json_object);
                    }
                });
                if (json_objects != undefined & json_objects.length > 0) {
                    json_objects = json_objects[0];
                }
                resolve(json_objects);
            };             
        
        // Tell JS To Start Reading The File.. You could delay this if desired
            reader.readAsBinaryString(oFile);
        });
    }
```

Но мне в объекте нужны не все поля книги Excel, а только определенные. Я сначала пытался удалять не нужные свойства следующим способом:

```
    //Удаление лишних полей из json-объектов
 properties=["oIDobject", "personalAccount", "idAccrual"];
        function removePropertysJsonObjects(jsonObjects, properties) {

            for (i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length;i++){

                jsonObjects[i]=removePropertysJsonObj(jsonObjects[i], properties);
            }
            return jsonObjects;
        }

        //Удаление лишних полей из json-объекта
        function removePropertysJsonObj(jsonObj, properties) {

            for (property in jsonObj) {

                if (properties.indexOf(property) == -1) {

                    delete 'jsonObj.' +'property';
                }
            }
            return jsonObj;
        }
```

Этот вариант не сработал вот в этой части:

```
delete 'jsonObj.' +'property';
```

Далее пытался применить функцию select в функции конвертации Excel in json (в интернете её нашел), но мне  выдает ошибку, что нет такой функции:

```
json_object.select("oIDobject personalAccount idAccrual dateAccrual summAccrual datePayment summPayment")
```

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

Может быть это возможно сделать на этапе чтения листа книги Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть массив `json` и поля которые не нужны, то поступайте проще.

```js
let jsonArray = [{
  "id": 1, 
  "oIDobject": "1", 
  "personalAccount": "1", 
  "idAccrual": "1"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 2, 
    "oIDobject": "2", 
    "personalAccount": "2", 
    "idAccrual": "2"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 3, 
    "oIDobject": "3", 
    "personalAccount": "3", 
    "idAccrual": "3"
  }
]
properties=["oIDobject", "personalAccount", "idAccrual"];

let result = jsonArray.map(
    item =>Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(item).filter(
          ([key,value]) => !properties.includes(key)
        )
       )
     );


console.log(result);
```